# Can't fill any fields in WinSCP

Tags: winscp

I try to connect to an FTP and when I'm trying to fill the fields like host name, port etc. Nothing happens. If I press "S" than save window pops up. So its like i'm using shortcuts but I don't.
It only happens in WinSCP.
I've already tried a portable version after re-installing it and having the same problem.

Comment: Do you get the same problem on other windows of WinSCP? Like on the mentioned Save dialog.